# Angular – Retrieving data from dynamic url based on parametrized route

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I want to get the data by route with parameters. In html the call is like this:

```
<a routerLink="my-component/2017">2017</a>
```

The component mainly looks like this:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {
  year: string;
  destination: any[];

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute,
              private _info: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const urlBase = 'http://...';
    this.subsUrl = this._route.paramMap.subscribe(
                  params => { this.year = params.get('year'); });

    this._info.url = urlBase + this.year;
    this.subsTree = this._info.getJsonData()
                              .subscribe(resultArray => this.destination = resultArray,
                                         error => alert(error));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subsTree.unsubscribe();
    this.subsUrl.unsubscribe();
  }
```

and the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  url: string;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getJsonData() {
    return this._http
      .get(this.url)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

The service returns correctly the data for a single parameter (the year). My problem is that if I change the year the data doesn’t change, until I manually refresh the page.

Comment: I would suggest reading the documentation and instead of `subscribe` to the params, use `switchMap` and do all of your data fetching there https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `this._route.paramMap` and your component name is `MyComponent`
I would suggest you to update your `routerLink` as below

```
<a [routerLink]="['/my']" [queryParams]="{year:'2017'}">2017</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `queryParams` with routerLink to build the url.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/my-component']" [queryParams]="{year:2017}">
  2017
</a>
```

The final URL will be:

```
http://localhost:3000/my-component?year=2017
```